# Multiple conditionals in php

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
if
(
  ($page_num >=10 && $page_num<= 20)  || 
  ($page_num >= 21 && $page_num =< 30) || 
  ($page_num >=31 && $page_num =<40)
){
     if($i==1){
       $i = $page_num;
     }
 }
```

I am trying to achieve multiple conditionals using the above in PHP. I tried it and it kept outputting an error, so I don't know if I am making a mistake or what I am trying above is not possible in PHP or programming.

> The error message
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:addsdcredit.php on line 398

Comment: Isn't this the same as `$page_num >= 10 && $page_num <= 40`? Why do you need 3 conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have =< on your code, change them like this: <= .
check http://php.net/manual/fa/language.operators.precedence.php.
Hope it helps.

```
$page_num = 11;
$i=1;
if(($page_num >=10 && $page_num<= 20)  || ($page_num >= 21 && $page_num <= 30) || ($page_num >=31 && $page_num <=40)){
     if($i==1){
       $i = $page_num;
       }
 }
```